# How to make different fonts for category labels in JFreeChart

Tags: java, font-face, jfreechart

I have a list of benchmark scores and one or two selected smartphones there, so I need to highlight those smartphones. I already did this with different bar colors, but I also want to change the font of a smartphone name—make it bold at least, but only for selected smartphones, not entire category labels.

[image: What i have]

To paint the bars I use the code below, but I don't know how to customize the font for category label as well:

```
public class MyBarRenderer extends StackedBarRenderer {
    //BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
    private ArrayList<Integer> selectedSmartphones;
    public MyBarRenderer (ArrayList<Integer> s) {
        selectedSmartphones = s;

        this.setSeriesPaint(0, new Color(255,133,0));
        this.setSeriesPaint(1, new Color(255,172,83));
        this.setSeriesPaint(2, new Color(211,110,0));
    }

    //renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.getColor("FFAC53"));
    @Override
    public Paint getItemPaint(int series, int category) {
        if (selectedSmartphones.contains(category)) {

                switch (series) {
                    case 0:
                        return new Color(81, 189, 230);

                    case 1:
                        return new Color(7, 167, 229);

                    case 2:
                        return new Color(2, 97, 133);

                    default:
                        return Color.blue;
                }

        } else {
                switch (series) {
                    case 0:
                        return new Color(255, 133, 0);

                    case 1:
                        return new Color(255, 172, 83);

                    case 2:
                        return new Color(211, 110, 0);

                    default:
                        return Color.orange;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: What i need]

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer that I was looking for all week.

```
CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
domainAxis.setTickLabelFont(strMyCategory,
    new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 13));
```

Where `strMyCategory` (a `Comparable` type `String`) is the exact category label that needs to be bold or have another font.